# Array for 4 dimension initializing

Tags: c#

An `array` of 3 dimensions initializes like this.

```
int[,,] arr = new int[2,3,3] {{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}, {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}};
```

How do you initialize this in 4 dimensions `array` or more?

```
int[,,,] arr = new int[3,6,5,2] // how to initialize as above?
```

Comment: Exactly the same, with just a deeper level of nesting...

Comment: who to do the deep level of nesting

Comment: Did you try to initialize it?

Comment: @user2741936: You must do it!

Answer (score 3):

If you want an example just like yours, it would be like this:

```
int[, , ,] a = new int[2, 3, 3, 3] { 
    { 
        { 
            { 1, 2, 3 }, 
            { 4, 5, 6 }, 
            { 7, 8, 9 } 
        }, 
        { 
            { 1, 2, 3 }, 
            { 4, 5, 6 }, 
            { 7, 8, 9 } 
        }, 
        { 
            { 1, 2, 3 }, 
            { 4, 5, 6 }, 
            { 7, 8, 9 } 
        } 
    }, 
    { 
        { 
            { 1, 2, 3 }, 
            { 4, 5, 6 }, 
            { 7, 8, 9 } 
        }, 
        { 
            { 1, 2, 3 }, 
            { 4, 5, 6 }, 
            { 7, 8, 9 } 
        }, 
        { 
            { 1, 2, 3 }, 
            { 4, 5, 6 }, 
            { 7, 8, 9 } 
        } 
    } 
};
```

Comment: Thank You !! SAM how the nesting is done can u explain this is 4D array if i move to 5D array or more.. then what is the concept behind. to initialize or proper nesting..

Comment: Actually you need to do something like this for `n dimension` array:
`int[,,,...,,,] a = new int[i,j,...,k]{i n-1 dimension arrays};`
in my example you could find 2 3d arrays (3×3×3) and believe me, initialization in this way gives you a bad headache with high dimensions and large sizes.

Comment: yeah sam !! u r right its a bad headache with high dimensions. one thing more where r this high dimensions used ..

Comment: Honestly I didn't use a 3d array much and a 4d never! I prefer other data structures such as dictionaries (a nested dictionary is much preferable than a high dimension array for me).

Comment: Hey sam pls explain this {i n-1 dimension arrays}.. with example if possible pls..

Comment: I mean you need n-1 dimension array i times. in my example i is 2 and n is 4, so I need 2 3d arrays. It is applicable to these 3d arrays. you need 3 2d arrays for each one and so on.